# Errors when using self-defined function under lapply

Tags: r, list, group-by, dplyr, lapply

Need help! I have a `list`of data frames,and each `dataframe` is in the same length and format:

```
> print(train_I_new_env[["Resample01.train"]])
          variable       Date Marketcap Monthly_return asset4_new_EnvScore
4     US90214J1016 2016-04-29   1421622   2.153255e-01             11.1063
5     US90214J1016 2016-05-31   1421622  -6.801530e-03             11.1063
7     US90214J1016 2016-07-29   1421622   1.734417e-01             11.1063
8     US90214J1016 2016-08-31   1421622   1.023900e-02             11.1063
9     US90214J1016 2016-09-30   1421622   8.017330e-02             11.1063
```

I want to apply a calculation process to each one of the data frames. So I firstly formed a function with `dplyr`:

```
group <- function(df, var1, var2, var3){
  var1 <-  enquo(var1); var2 <-  enquo(var2); var3 <-  enquo(var3);
  df %>% 
    group_by(!!var1) %>% 
    summarise(return = sum(var2*var3, na.rm = TRUE)/ sum (var3, na.rm = 
TRUE)*100)
}
```

Then applied this function under `lapply`:

```
lapply(train_R_new_env, function(x) group(x,Date,Monthly_return,Marketcap))
```

Then a warning message accured:

> Error in var2 * var3 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

I then checked the class of `Monthly_return` and `Marketcap`, and they are both numeric. I'm a noob in R, and I'm not sure about the way to do the calculation, any alternative solution is also welcomed.

Comment: You need `!!var2` and `!!var3` the same as you've used `!!var1`

Comment: For debugging, you should check that you can successfully call your function on a single data frame before trying to map or apply that function across a whole list. But you also aren't calling your function in the `lapply`—you're calling a function called `group`. Why?

Comment: @camille Thank you so much! I corrected the var2 and var3 and it worked! Reason for the error is that I had completly no idea on the calculation across a list, so I searched other similar questions and built the function on their solutions. Thank you for pointing it out, the function called `group` was a typing mistake of copying the wrong codes, I'll correct it.